# How to view the entire Rails console history?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know how to view the "history" in the rails console?

Pressing the up arrow lets me iterate through recent commands, but I'd like to see them all together in a list. I'm basically looking for the rails equivalent of the Unix `history` utility.

Is this possible in rails?  If so, how?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Look at `~/.irb-history`, you will find the history there.

Comment: hm... for the record, it's actually `~/.irb-history` (with a dash, not an underscore) on my machine. Not sure why. I'm on a Mac and using RVM.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Weird, I have both files, but the one with `_` seems to be more up to date than the other. Strange.

Comment: I have both files too, but in my case `-` is more up to date.  Strange indeed!

Comment: It's a hyphen on my Ubuntu laptop & and an underscore on our Ubuntu server.  Odd indeed: they have the same version of ruby but it's hard-installed on the server and rvm-installed on my laptop.  Wonder if it's something to do with rvm?

Comment: I found it in `~/.local/share/pry/pry_history` presumably due to a pry-rails gem in dev requirements in the venvs I was using

Comment: I also found it in "~/.local/"... If that's the default for ruby venvs they could have come up with a better naming...

Answer (score 79):

The best equivalent to the `history` command would be

```
puts Readline::HISTORY.to_a
```

inside the IRB session. This has the advantage that no filesystem logging to any of the`$HOME/.*_history` files needs to be configured (as is the case in AWS elastic beanstalk instances).

Comment: In newer versions it's Reline instead of Readline

`puts Reline::HISTORY.to_a`

Answer (score 25):

I've tried the accepted answer, but our server didn't have a `~/.irb-history`.

As it turned out, the history was kept in `~/.pry_history`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also here. Maybe when using pry gem, then it'll be stored in `~/.pry_history`, instead of `~/.irb_history`.

Answer (score 5):

Since we're already in the console,

```
lines = File.read("#{ENV['HOME']}/.pry_history");
```

or

```
lines = File.read("#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-history");
```

then,

```
puts lines
```

Comment: history = File.read("#{ENV['HOME']}/.pry_history").split('\n')

Answer (score 2):

Try `CTRL+R` to open the search in the history

Answer (score 0):

We can view it by using following command in console

```
cat ~/.irb-history
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> The best equivalent to the `history` command would be

currently (`Pry version 0.14.1 on Ruby 3.0.2` for me) there is actually a `history` command which is an alias for `hist`.